# Ошибка ndk_project_path=null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

Cтолкнулся со следующей проблемой, есть андроид проект использующий `NDK` файлы. Все работало прекрасно в один прекрасный день решил обновить rxJava на следующую версию. И после этого вылезла такая ошибка:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Study\Experiments\Cpp_NDKExper\NdkExampl2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-25 NDK_OUT=D:\Study\Experiments\Cpp_NDKExper\NdkExampl2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Study\Experiments\Cpp_NDKExper\NdkExampl2\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Много чего перепробовал, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, например запускал с папки

```
C:\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle ndk-build.cmd
```

В консоли выводится ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сносить `android SDK` и a`ndroidStudio` но это тоже не помогло. Опять выходить эта ошибка.

Теперь не знаю что делать. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

File -> ProjectStructure -> слева выбрать SDK Location -> в поле NDK Location выбрать место, где хранится NDK. Что то вроде /home/yourUserName/android-sdk/ndk-bundle

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, там уже стоит строка "C:\Android_SDK\ndk-bundle".

Comment: жаль, это было бы самым простым решением )) попробуйте тогда ещё вот этот ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453085/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugndk-failed-to-run-this-command-ndk

Comment: спасибо, но мне не очень понятно причина, почему это произошло. Все работало и вдруг ничего не работает. И почему переустанвка adroid studio, android NDK, SDK не помогла ?