# При попытке заимпортить OpenCV в android studio вылезает ошибка

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opencv

Error:(115) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
и
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'D:\AndroidSDK\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\Projects\Android\OpenCvTest\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_PLATFORM=android-25 NDK_OUT=D:\Projects\Android\OpenCvTest\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\Projects\Android\OpenCvTest\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\lib APP_ABI=all}

Comment: Проверьте, не поможет ли вам [вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/638856/223089)

Comment: Это не очень то помогает. В сотнях видосов про openCV установку в android studio делают показано как, но это у меня так не работает...вылезает эта ошибка.